# Retaining and Migrating Actor / Service State

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've been looking at using service fabric as a platform for a new solution that we are building and I am getting hung up on data / stage management.  I really like the concept of reliable services and the actor model and as we have started to prototype out some things it seems be working well.

With that beings said I am getting hung up on state management and how I would use it in a 'real' project.  I am also a little concerned with how the data feels like a black box that I can't interrogate or manipulate directly if needed. A couple scenarios I've thought about are:

1. How would I share state between two developers on a project?  I have an Actor and as long as I am debugging the actor my state is maintained, replicated, etc.  However when I shut it down the state is all lost.  More importantly someone else on my team would need to set up the same data as I do, this is fine for transactional data - but certain 'master' data should just be constant.
2. Likewise I am curious about how I would migrate data changes between environments.  We periodically pull production data down form our SQL Azure instance today to keep our test environment fresh, we also push changes up from time to time depending on the requirements of the release.

I have looked at the backup and restore process, but it feels cumbersome, especially in the development scenario.  Asking someone to (or scripting the) restore on every partition of every stateful service seems like quite a bit of work.

I think that the answer to both of these questions is that I can use the stateful services, but I need to rely on an external data store for anything that I want to retain.  The service would check for state when it was activated and use the stateful service almost as a write-through cache.  I'm not suggesting that this needs to be a uniform design choice, more on a service by service basis - depending on the service needs.

Does that sound right, am I overthinking this, missing something, etc?

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to share Actor state between developers, you can use a shared cluster. (in Azure or on-prem). Make sure you always do [upgrade-style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial) deployments, so state will survive. State is persisted if you [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-state-management) the Actor to do so.
2. You can migrate data by doing a [backup](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.BackupRestore) of all replica's of your service and restoring them on a different cluster. (have the service running and trigger data-loss). It's cumbersome yes, but at this time it's the only way. (or store state externally)

Note that state is safe in the cluster, it's stored on disk and replicated. There's no need to have an external store, provided you do regular state backups and keep them outside the cluster. Stateful services can be more than just caches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured that my options were something like that.  The upgrade-style deployments are an interesting option that I will have to look into.  For now I have created a state provider for certain actors that is pushing the state out to document db.